# Need to load image as modal on click in bootstrap css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried loading a modal image on clicking a image by fading the background.

It works for me. But for multiple images how can I load the image which I have clicked based on the image id without writting multiple modal div.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <head>
     <title>Sample</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link href="./dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
     <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="./dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <!-- Image trigger modal -->
       <img src="http://sheshtawy.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/extra-firefox.png" id="img1" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="min-height:300px;height:300px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" alt="Responsive image">

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="http://sheshtawy.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/extra-firefox.png">
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Image trigger modal -->
       <img src="http://sheshtawy.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/extra-firefox.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="min-height:300px;height:300px;" alt="Responsive image">
           <img src="http://sheshtawy.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/cairo_pollution.jpg?w=250"/>
           <img src="http://sheshtawy.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/img_4749.jpg?w=250"/>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img id="mimg" src="">
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**Script**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img').on('click',function()
                {
                    var sr=$(this).attr('src'); 
                    $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q8CYC/5/)

Comment: How do you make this work when your images are using relative paths?