# Bootstrap modal disappears the moment it shows up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138307/need-to-load-image-as-modal-on-click-in-bootstrap-css/32792489#32792489) to my thumbnail, but it only works partially.

My problem is that it disappears the moment it shows up.

What might be a solution?

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0346/9741/products/Spaniel_PNG_1024x1024.png?v=1436758378" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <div class="caption" >
        <h4>Project One</h4>
        <p>In this project I used HTML, CSS and Javascript.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="mimg" src="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img').on('click',function(){
        var sr=$(this).attr('src');                     
        $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: need more clues. Try inspecting live html in browser dev tools and see if modal is there and if css conflict might be causing issues. Also is image being clicked inside an anchor or other tag that may have other events?

Comment: http://codepen.io/RycerzPegaza/pen/meOeBq there is no css, and this is the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a conflict with the auto initalizing attributes on the image conflicting with the manual `modal.show()`

```
<img data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" src="...">
```

These attributes will already toggle the same modal.

Either remove the attributes or don't manually call `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

It works fine if you comment out the script