# Bootstrap modal fails to show image

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been trying to get this bootstrap modal to work without any luck. Been looking at similar problem here as well but none has helped me.

My problem is that the images does not show. The window is there but no image inside it.

Anyway here's the code.
Edit: I have looked at [Need to load image as modal on click in bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138307/need-to-load-image-as-modal-on-click-in-bootstrap-css), I even tried the code and did not get that to work either for me. There for a new question, my bad if that was wrong. :/

```
    <hr class="featurette-divider">
      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <h4>Tidningen City Malmö</h4> 
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="citymalmo_frontpage.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="citymalmo_frontpage_thumbnail.png" alt="City Malmö Förstasida"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="citymalmo_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="citymalmo_page_thumbnail.png" alt="City Malmö sida"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <hr class="featurette-divider">
      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <h4>Sveriges Radio P4</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="srp4_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="srp4_page_thumbnail.png" alt="SR P4"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.getSrc').click(function() {
        var src =$(this).attr('src');

     $('.showPic').attr('src', src);
     });
    </script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="" class="showPic">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have bootstrap.min.js loaded.

Comment: did you add jquery to your <head>? :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to load image as modal on click in bootstrap css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138307/need-to-load-image-as-modal-on-click-in-bootstrap-css)

Comment: @ Adi Azarya
well no it's loaded at the bottom as suggested at Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "getSrc" class to  tag

```
<hr class="featurette-divider">
      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Tidningen City Malmö</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="citymalmo_frontpage.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block getSrc" src="flag.png" alt="City Malmö Förstasida">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="citymalmo_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block getSrc" src="flag.png" alt="City Malmö sida"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">
      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Sveriges Radio P4</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <a class="tumbnail" href="#" data-image="srp4_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block getSrc" src="flag.png" alt="SR P4"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Next put both classes img-responsive showPic in same class = ""

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive showPic" src="" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        console.log( "ready!" );
     $('.getSrc').click(function() {
         console.log("hello");
        var src =$(this).attr('src');

     $('.showPic').attr('src', src);
     });
    });
</script>
```

Please note: You need to load jquery javascript, bootstrap css and javascript libraries

Here is a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/mkfLmLx1/

Comment: I've tried your thoughts but without any luck, still the same issue for me, the window opens up but no picture. Same as Gavgrif suggestion :(

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to move a few scripts up to the <head> tag, not down by the </body> tag... my bad ;(

Answer (score 0):

Three issues - first you are trying to get the src on an onclick of ".getSrc" - but you have not designated that class in the code. You will need to add it as below:

Second you have a typo with the "tumbnail" and third you are  using "this" to get the src of the image but the image is nested within an `<a>` element - so the "this" will refer to the `<a>` and not the image within it..

```
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="thumbnail getSrc" href="#" data-image="citymalmo_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="citymalmo_page_thumbnail.png" alt="City Malmö sida"></a>
```

You need to find the image within the a element and get that src (or use a data attribute on the a like the one that already there.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.getSrc').click(function() {
    var src =$(this).find('img').attr('src');
 $('.showPic').attr('src', src);
 });
</script>
```

if you want to use the data attribute on the a then it would be:

```
<a class="thumbnail getSrc" href="#" data-source="citymalmo_page_thumbnail.png" data-image="citymalmo_page.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="citymalmo_page_thumbnail.png" alt="City Malmö sida"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.getSrc').click(function() {
    var src =$(this).attr('data-source');
 $('.showPic').attr('src', src);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your thoughts but without any luck, still the same issue for me, the window opens up but no picture. Same as edruplers suggestion :(